# Yii2 rest api related data fails

Tags: php, yii2

Am trying to return related data but it fails

SO in my controller i have

```
 $query = EmployeeTasks::with('employee')->find()->all();

return ["data"=>$query]
```

IN my EmployeeTasks i have the details relationship like

```
    public function getEmployee()
      {
       return $this->hasOne(CasualEmployees::className(), ['id' => 'employee_id']);
     }
```

But the data returned doesnt have the employee data even though there should be

Where am i going wrong?

Dumpo of $query has

```
[{name:'paint', created_at:1532508029....}] it doesnt have employee
```

Comment: please attach dump of $query

Comment: @bxN5 ive attached the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`asArray()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#asArray()-detail):

```
$data = EmployeeTasks::find()->with('employee')->asArray()->all();
```